# How to "scroll" a view of indeterminate size?

Tags: android, view, scroll

I have written a custom View which is used to display a tileable pattern, and want the user to be able to zoom in (which I've got covered) and then move around within the pattern.

Because the pattern is tileable it means that there are effectively no bounds on it.  In theory a user could just keep scrolling left (right, up, or down) forever. In reality I would be using a modulus to adjust the virtual position.

I'm just not sure where to start. Would I use something with scrollbars? I'm not sure that makes any sense, because as I said the viewable area is effectively infinite.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided a scrollview was unnecessary.  All I really had to do was handle the touch events and then adjust the virtual coordinates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a scrollview with the scrollbars turned off.

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```